# How to pass the value of a variable from an HTML page into a python flask backend application which will be loaded in an HTML iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, flask, iframe

I am using python flask for back end i.e., app.py file for routes, and html and JavaScript for front end, once user login's with business email, I will be splitting and sending only "domain_name" from entered logged in email to dashboard.html page. In the dashboard.html page there are few buttons when clicked it will open in iframe and will call different script(assume application1) running in different port. Now I want to send this "domain_name" variable from dashboard.html to that application1 backend file, i.e., app.py How to achieve it?

This is dashboard.html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style-dashboard.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="points">
            <button data-src="http://123.23.23.23:5002"><span>Application1</span></button>
            <button data-src="http://123.23.23.23:5003"><span>Application2</span></button>
            <button data-src="http://123.23.23.23:5004"><span>Application3</span></button>
        </div>
        <iframe class="iframe-container" id="iframe-container" src=""></iframe>
    </div>
    <script>
        testDomainName = "{{ domain_name }}";
        console.log(testDomainName)
        const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.points button');
        const iframe = document.getElementById('iframe-container');

        buttons.forEach(button => {
            button.addEventListener('click', function () {
                // Remove the 'selected-button' class from all buttons
                buttons.forEach(btn => {
                    btn.classList.remove('selected-button');
                });

                // Add the 'selected-button' class to the clicked button
                this.classList.add('selected-button');
                
                const src = this.getAttribute('data-src');
                iframe.src = src;

                const screenHeight = window.innerHeight;
                const spaceAtBottom = 20;
                iframe.style.height = `${screenHeight - 90 - spaceAtBottom}px`;
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Since the 2 of them have different html pages, I am not able to retrieve data using request.form['domain_name']. So how to send the value of "domain_name" from dashboard.html to application1?

When i click on the "application1" button, it should send the value of "domain_name" to the backend i.e., application1's app.py file.

I tried using javascript in dashboard.html page to send data when "application1" button is clicked, I am able to load data of application1 but it will leave the the dashboard page "123.23.23.23:5001/dashboard" and will go to "123.23.23.23:5002/process" and it will also mess up all the content of dashboard.html page.

I modified application1 button to
`<button data-src="http://123.23.23.23:5002/process"><span>Typosquatting Domains</span></button>`

and added this javascript

```
if (this.id === "typsquattingButton") {
    const domainName = "{{ domain_name }}";
    console.log(domainName);

    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", "post");
    form.setAttribute("action", src);

    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    input.setAttribute("name", "domain");
    input.setAttribute("value", domainName);

    form.appendChild(input);

    document.body.appendChild(form);

    form.submit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell from your description what security precautions you want to take.

The easiest way to send a variable to another server via the iFrame is via URL parameters in a GET request.

###### Website of the first server.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .active {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a 
                    class="nav-btn" 
                    href="http://127.0.0.1:5000/process?domain={{ domain }}" 
                    target="my-iframe"
                >App1 (localhost:5000)</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a 
                    class="nav-btn" 
                    href="http://127.0.0.1:5001/process?domain={{ domain }}" 
                    target="my-iframe"
                >App2 (localhost:5001)</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <iframe name="my-iframe"></iframe>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {
            const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-btn');
            btns.forEach(btn => {
                btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
                    btns.forEach(elem => { elem.classList.remove('active'); });
                    this.classList.add('active');
                });
            });
        })();
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

###### Endpoint of the second server.

```py
@app.route('/process')
def process():
    domain = request.args.get('domain')
    return render_template('process.html', **locals())
```

Another option is to send a value to the iFrame via the [Messaging API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage), which then further processes the received data. It should be noted that rules for cross-domain requests do not exist without a reason.

###### JavaScript for the parent frame.

```js
(function() {
    const iframe = document.querySelector('iframe[name="my-iframe');
    iframe.addEventListener('load', function() {
        const data = { domain: {{ domain | tojson }}};
        iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify(data), '*'); 
    });

    const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-btn');
    btns.forEach(btn => {
        btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
            btns.forEach(elem => { elem.classList.remove('active'); });
            this.classList.add('active');
        });
    });
})();
```

###### JavaScript for the iframe.

```js
(function() {
    window.addEventListener('message', event => {
        const origin = event.origin; 
        if (event.origin == 'http://127.0.0.1:5000') {
            const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
            console.log(data);

            // Use the data and possibly submit a form from here.
        }
    });
})();
```